# PACT: How to match specific dateTime format in pact jvm DSL?

Tags: java, pact

Using pact jvm DSL with spring boot (.timestamp(name, format, example) I can specify both:

```
.timestamp("start", "dd-MM-yyyyy'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'", Instant.parse("2020-10-06T20:48:58.402Z"))
```

and

```
.timestamp("start", "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'", Instant.parse("2020-10-06T20:48:58.402Z"))
```

or even

```
.timestamp("start", "dd-MM-yyyyyyy'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'", Instant.parse("2020-10-06T20:48:58.402Z"))
```

and the test still passes.

My real provider service errors if you send the date **dd-MM-yyyy** rather than **yyyy-MM-dd**, but I can't figure out how you're supposed to get the test on the consumer side to fail when it incorrectly sends the wrong format JSON timestamp to the provider API.

I.e. the bit that looks like this:

```
    @Test
    @PactTestFor(pactMethod = "postTheThing")
    public void pactWithProvider() {
      client.makeApiCall(testPayload);
    }
```

Comment: I think the test cases will pass, because pact framework does not verify the data, but only json elements in the response compared to the expected pact file. For Example, the field start is changed to something startDate, but expected field in the pact file is 'start', then your test case fails.

Answer (score 0):

Consumer tests fail only if you add some validation. It is supposed that pacts convert to **stubs** on the consumer side and that's it.

Just add some `mockition #verify` validation in your consumer test.